# Facebook Invite Tokens vs FBWebDialogs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am about to submit my iOS app to the app store. It's a first version of the app so it doesn't have visible iTunes Connect link yet.

I am trying to develop "invite your Facebook friends" functionality. I started by following this tutorial. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2
I am able to get Invite Tokens but I have no idea how to use it to send requests to other users. There is nothing in the documentation about it. Is it possible at all?

After couple of days of torture I tried to use FBWebDiealogs. Now I am using this

```
    [FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"Try MyApp"
 title:nil
 parameters:nil
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback

         }
     }
 }];
```

to get web view which presents my friends and you are able to get invite. The problem is that you get only invite on the web and not on the IOS device. Does it have to do with the fact that my app is not approved by Apple so App Store link doesn't exist yet. My game is only for IOS so there is no need to have canvas platform like Facebook requires. Is there a way to avoid that?

Where to go from here?